# Has anyone tried to join or blend items from monday.com connector data source with external dataset such as Excel spreadsheet, on Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, connector, monday.com

I'm trying to connect boards and items that were connected through Alpha Serve with Excel spreadsheet that holds complementary data and sharing the same fields. Can't find any option to create join or blend options for the two data sources.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Connect to Data:

- Open Tableau Desktop and go to the "Data Source" tab.
- Connect to your primary data source.

2. Add Additional Data Source:

- In the Data Source tab, find your primary data source.
- To add an external data source, click on the “Add” button or drag and drop the data source file onto the canvas.

3. Define Relationships:

- Tableau may auto-create relationships, but you might need to do this manually.
- Drag and drop fields from one data source onto corresponding fields in the other to create relationships.

4. Choose Join Type:

- Right-click on the relationship line and pick the join type (Inner, Left, Right, Outer) based on your merging needs.

5. Blend Data:

- If your sources lack common fields, use data blending.
- Drag fields from the main data source to the secondary one in the “Data” pane.

6. Build Views:

- Once your data is joined or blended, head back to the “Sheet” tab.
- Now, you can start creating visualizations by using fields from both data sources.